# How does Spark View Engine's performance compare to ASP.NET?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, spark-view-engine, performance

I'm interested in using [Spark](http://sparkviewengine.com/) for an open source pet project of mine that runs with the asp.net mvc framework. I wonder if anyone has real experience with it and knows how it performs compared to the normal asp.net view engine?

I know that marketwatch.com runs asp.net mvc and Spark.

Comment: I don't think that Spark link is correct. Probably has been changed: https://github.com/SparkViewEngine/spark

Answer (score 13):

The view templates are parsed to generate and compile a class that does nothing more than write output. After the first request of a view there's no real work being done other than to create an instance of that type and render.

It's been profiled for cpu and memory costing pretty extensively. I believe it's safe to assume there's nothing measurably slower in Spark - and in general it's unlikely the rendering in either Spark or WebForms view engines would be a bottleneck in a real-world application.

Answer (score 2):

[Here](http://mogadanez.blogspot.com/2009/07/aspnet-mvc-speed-test.html) is a benchmark done to compare WebForms to Spark. Spark scores 36% slower than WebForms, which probably is worth paying for extra flexibility that one gets with Spark.